# Articolo con i nomi propri: sì o no?

Tags: articles, name, proper-nouns

Mi sapreste dire se è corretto usare l’articolo davanti ai nomi propri (grammaticalmente parlando)? Per citare qualche esempio: *la Maria, la Giuseppina, la Stefania* . E nei cognomi come ad esempio: *l'Alighieri*?

Comment: Si usa, ma non so se sia corretto nel caso dei nomi, in specie se maschili.

Comment: Lo usano per lo più in Toscana, ma non è corretto.

Comment: NO, è un errore grammaticale mettere l'articolo prima di un nome proprio, anche se è diffuso il suo utilizzo in molte regioni del nord Italia.